# Mouse sensitivity in Fallout 3 menus too high

Tags: fallout-3

I'm trying to lower the mouse sensitivity in Fallout 3 to an acceptable level.

I have done the following changes to my `fallout.ini` file:

```
ForegroundMouseAccelBase=0
fForegroundMouseAccelTop=0
fForegroundMouseBase=0
fForegroundMouseMult=0
```

The only thing I can find that regards the sensitivity is `fMouseSensitivity`, found in `falloutprefs.ini`. Changing this seems to make no difference to the menu sensitivity.

Anyone know what I need to change?

Comment: Just curious, is there something wrong with the sensitivity slider?

Comment: It only changes the sensitivity while in-game, not for menus.
I think I'll just use my xbox controller, I tried lowering the DPI of my mouse but 400 is too low.

Answer (score 1):

It might be solved by [disabling mouse acceleration or mouse precision in Windows](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1953585/completely-turn-mouse-acceleration-windows.html) or whatever OS you are using.

Note that, if you're not using FOSE, or any other software that circumvents the official game launcher, the Fallout 3 INI's will be reset on every launch.